# Is there an Android Studio activities for lower version APIs?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, android-2.3-gingerbread

I just started programming using Android Studio and it's so cute. But at first compile some errors occurred.

I added a Login Activity and found out that this activity does not support programming for older phones with API9.

**Is there an Android Studio activities for lower version APIs such as API9 (Android 2.3.3) ?**

Comment: Once you will create project with android studio, it will include support library in it. Just create login activity and replace Activity with AppCompatActivity!

Answer (score 0):

The way to support earlier API versions is through the official Android Support libraries. Mostly these are backported versions of more recent features added in later API levels.

See http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html for more details.

If you create a new project using the Android Studio wizard and set the minimum SDK level to 9 for example, it will automatically include support library dependencies for you.

Comment: API Level 9 isn't listed in the Dashboard anymore. Better start with API Level 8, which is still listed.

Comment: @DerGolem Making a API 9 minimum project worked for me - there's a difference between minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion.

Comment: Making API Level 8 as minSdkVersion works for me. And it supports the **still alive** Froyo, and the **dead** API Level 9 as well. Of course, `min` and `target` are two different beasts and shouldn't be confused.